# How to expand an iterable stored as a single value in Python Pandas? (a.k.a. reverse groupby)

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
Index Letter Numbers
1     A      [1, 11]
2     B      [2, 22]
3     C      [3, 33]
```

And I want to "expand" the list of numbers just so each number has it's own row, like this:

```
Index Letter Numbers
1     A      1
2     A      11
3     B      2
4     B      22
5     C      3
6     C      33
```

I tried to achieve this by using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Letter': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'Numbers': [[1, 11], [2, 22], [3, 33]]
})

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    for num in row['Numbers']:
        new_row = row.copy()
        new_row['Numbers'] = num
        df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

df = df.loc[df.apply(lambda x: type(x['Numbers']) != list, axis=1)]
```

It works for the example, but in a larger DataFrame (a few hundred thousand lines for example) it takes a lot of time. Is there a better, more optimized way to do it? I tried using the apply method, but it clears my DataFrame for some reason...

Comment: Use `explode`: `df.explode('Numbers')`

Comment: `explode` is the most user friendly option. But it can be slow because operations like this don't scale particularly well. If performance is a real requirement, there are ways to use `numpy` to reconstruct the DataFrame. If you know all lists are the same size it can be very simple, otherwise you need a lot of care and it can get a bit messier

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, if you don't have huge data to parse, it's really been easy to use `df.explode()`

```
>>> df
  Letter  Numbers
0      A  [1, 11]
1      B  [2, 22]
2      C  [3, 33]
```

### Solution 1

```
>>> df = df.explode('Numbers')
>>> df
  Letter Numbers
0      A       1
0      A      11
1      B       2
1      B      22
2      C       3
2      C      33
```

### Solution 2:

This is faster with `np.repeat` ...

```
>>> lens = [len(item) for item in df['Numbers']]
>>> pd.DataFrame( {"Letter" : np.repeat(df['Letter'].values,lens), "Numbers" : np.hstack(df['Numbers'])})
  Letter  Numbers
0      A        1
1      A       11
2      B        2
3      B       22
4      C        3
5      C       33
```

Other Solutions ..

```
df.explode('Numbers', ignore_index=True)
# df.explode('Numbers').reset_index(drop=True)

  Letter Numbers
0      A       1
1      A      11
2      B       2
3      B      22
4      C       3
5      C      33
```

with apply + pd.Series

```
 >>> df.set_index('Letter').Numbers.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=0).rename(columns={0:'Numbers'})
  Letter  Numbers
0      A        1
1      A       11
0      B        2
1      B       22
0      C        3
1      C       33
```

## Note:

Meanwhile, i see already an interesting answer for the same [here another Solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Use `explode` to expand values vertically:

```
>>> df.explode('Numbers', ignore_index=True)

  Letter Numbers
0      A       1
1      A      11
2      B       2
3      B      22
4      C       3
5      C      33
```

Use `apply(pd.Series`) to expand values horizontally:

```
>>> df.join(df['Numbers'].apply(pd.Series)
                         .add_prefix('Numbers_')) \
      .drop(columns='Numbers')

  Letter  Numbers_0  Numbers_1
0      A          1         11
1      B          2         22
2      C          3         33
```